# jupyter notebook で保存したグラフが正常に表示されない

Tags: r, jupyter-notebook

jupyter notebookのR言語で、plotを使ってグラフを出力しました。

`File>Download as>HTML(.html)`で結果を保存したところ、以下のようにグラフが表示されません。何か解決方法はありますでしょうか。
環境はMacbook,ブラウザはChromeです。よろしくお願いいたします！！

**ダウンロードする前**
[image: ダウンロードする前]

**ダウンロードした後**
[image: ダウンロードした後]

[image: HTMLのコード部分]

Comment: 表示されていない部分のHTMLのコード（`<img src="`で始まる部分）はどうなっていますか？

Comment: HTMLコードの部分のスクリーンショットを追加いたしました！よろしくお願いします！！

Comment: `<img src="data:image/png;base64,`以降に、画像データ（Base64エンコードされた文字列）があるはずですが、無いですね。うーん。

Comment: 単に画像挿入するのもうまくいかなかったです..大学のレポートで使うので、とり急ぎ今回はスクリーンショットを添付しようと思います。

Comment: 私の環境では再現できなかったので、環境依存の問題と考えられます。OS、ブラウザ、Jupyter Notebookのバージョンも記載しておいてください（時間があるときに :-)）